# how to get started with Optaplanner

Tags: optaplanner

I looked at the user guide http://docs.jboss.org/optaplanner/release/6.1.0.Final/optaplanner-docs/html_single/index.html#d0e2669

I looked at the example code from git, but still feel quite lost about how to model my planning problem (for example some special TSP variant, let's say  TSPTW ). the way OptaPlanner user code is structured is that the user code is devided into several packages, and there is not a entire "end-to-end" flow of code, and as a developer I only see these "modules" , sort of. So as a result it's very difficult for me to figure out how to connect the dots, and how these "dots" interact together to accomplish the overall algorithm task.

the section in the link above "Model your planning problem " sort of touches on the above question I have, but still seems out of sync with the example code, so it's difficult to figure out how the current examples work, also it's difficult for me to see how to add my own special logic for the TSP variant .

is there a better "code walk-through" document to show the usage of the framework?

thanks
Yang

Comment: In [the latest model](http://docs.jboss.org/optaplanner/release/latest/optaplanner-docs/html_single/index.html#vehicleRouting), section "3.3.3.3. Domain model" there's an explanation of the VRPTW (including time windows) model.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look [here](http://old.appwriter.com/new-easier-optaplanner-example-project.html) this guy create a simple optaplanner project to test some concepts and learn how to use it.